# the ResultSet from combining data from two tables in JSP,Servlet

Tags: sql, jsp, join

I have thoses table

```
   table product(id,name)
   table component(id,name,quantity)
   table_product_component(p_id,C_id)
```

a product can have many components, a component can belong to many products.

How can I excute the JOIN query and get a ResultSet that will display the product name,component name and quantity ?

when I excute an sql query to return those, i usually store it in an ArrayList So in this case i create a new object of itemline that will store a Product,Component types. then I can store the result of the query in a ArrayList. So then I can simply write logic to display a notice if quantity is 0 and like that ?

the problem is i never used a view or relational table like                                          table_product_component(p_id,C_id) 
so am not sure how to query the dataset to get the result I am wanting

Any ideas,methods,codes,theories are welcome to help me in solving this are appreciated.

I actually need the servlet/JSP logic too

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have solved this in a certain way. I did with the java within the jsp

```
                  <%
            Cart cart = (Cart) session.getAttribute("cart");
            List<LineItem> items = cart.getItems();
            for (LineItem item : items) {
            Product product = item.getProduct();


        %> 

        <tr> 
            <td> 
                <form action="<%=response.encodeURL("DisplayCart")%>"> 
                    <input type="hidden" name="productId"  
                           value="<%=product.getId()%>"> 
                    <input type="text" size=2 name="quantity"  
                           value="<%=item.getQuantity()%>"> 
                    <input type="submit" value="Update"> 
                </form> 
            </td> 
            <td> 
                <%=product.getDescription()%> 
            </td>
            <td><%=product.getPrice()%></td>
            <td> 
                <form action="<%= response.encodeURL("DisplayCart")%>"> 
                    <input type="hidden" name="productId"  
                           value="<%=product.getId()%>"> 
                    <input type="hidden" name="quantity"  
                           value="0"> 
                    <input type="submit" value="RemoveButton"> 
                </form> 
            </td>
        <td>           
       <%
        String p = product.getId();        
        List<String> pcs = PcDb.selectCidFromPc(p);
        for (String temp : pcs) {

        Component component = ComponentDb.selectComponent(temp);
        int c = component.getQuantity(); 
        if(c==0){
        out.println("Product is not in stock at the moment, expect delays");
        }
        }
        %>  
        </td>
        </tr> 

        <% }%>
```